# Github Action Tab Workflow is Not running Error. This workflow has a workflow_dispatch event trigger

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a file which contain this:

```
name: CI


on: [push, workflow_dispatch]


jobs:

  build:


    runs-on: windows-latest


    steps:

    - name: Download

      run: Invoke-WebRequest https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-windows-amd64.zip -OutFile ngrok.zip

    - name: Extract

      run: Expand-Archive ngrok.zip

    - name: Auth

      run: .\ngrok\ngrok.exe authtoken $Env:NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN

      env:

        NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN }}

    - name: Enable TS

      run: Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server'-name "fDenyTSConnections" -Value 0

    - run: Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Remote Desktop"

    - run: Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp' -name "UserAuthentication" -Value 1

    - run: Set-LocalUser -Name "runneradmin" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "P@ssw0rd!" -Force)

    - name: Create Tunnel

      run: .\ngrok\ngrok.exe tcp 3389
```

but it was not running as workflow. I am very confused. Can anyone help me to resolve this? The repository is available [here](https://github.com/RyanOrion89/Trail-Pc).